# How to fix browser issue in wordpress theme development

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, wordpress-theming

I am learning to develop wordpress theme and I found some strange and irritating problem.

on the desktop, everything is fine but when I opened it from mobile phone It gives different look.

I am attaching two screenshots of google chrome and Firefox output.
Where Firefox is giving decent look but google chrome is giving text bigger and does not sound good.

How can I fix the coding so that both could look same.

[image: Firefox][image: Google Chrome]

HERE IS THE CODE OF CSS

```css
.home-2-article {
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba($font-color, .5);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    @media only screen and (max-device-width: 599px) {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-bottom: 3rem;
    }
    

    & > * {
        padding: .3rem;
    }

    &__thumbnail {
        flex: 0 0 35%;
        margin-right: 1rem;
        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 599px) {
            margin: 0;
        }
        img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    }

    &__wrapper {

        &__title  {
            h2 {
                font-size: 1.5em;

                @media only screen and (max-device-width: 599px) {
                    font-size: 3em;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                
            }
            
        }

        &__meta {
            display: flex;
            
            @media only screen and (max-device-width: 599px) {
                font-size: 1.7em;
                justify-items: center;
                justify-content: center
            }
            
            ;
            
            
            & > * {
                padding: 0.5rem;
            }
        }

        &__excerpt {
           padding-bottom: .5rem;
           p {
               font-size: 1em;

               @media only screen and (max-device-width: 599px) {
                   font-size: 2em;
                   padding: 0.3rem;
               }
           }
        }

        .home-2-article__rm {

            a {
                background-color: $primary-color-dark;
                padding: 0.2rem .6rem;
                color: white;
                
                
                @media only screen and (max-device-width: 599px) and (max-width: 599px) {
                font-size: 1.7em;
                text-align: center;
                display: block;
                }


                &:hover {
                    background-color: $primary-color; 
                    transition: 1s all ease-in-out;
                }
            }

               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to share code with a question of this nature.

Comment: Any HTML to go with this CSS?